# configure UItableView not to scroll on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How do I set  uitableView not to scroll So that it is fixed with two rows

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
  tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

if you wish to fix the size you sould set the frame to be for 2 row's size:

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(x_position,y_position,width,height);
```

good luck

Answer (score 2):

use this code:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```